# TCPDF displays blank PDF if query result is big

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a search form wherein it allows PDF download whenever you enter a search query on it. The problem here is that I can only download the PDF if there are only few numbers of result..

If result exceeds 80 records, it displays a blank page..

Please Advice,
Thanks.!

here's my code:

```
// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

//set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------


// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(0, $order_type, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 7);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ob_start();

if(!($query = mysql_query($this->sql)))
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());

if(($field_name=mysql_num_fields($query)) > 0) {
    $tableheader = '<table>';
    $tableheader .= '<tr>';
    $tableheader .= '<td>Rows</td>';
    for($x=0;$x<$field_name;$x++) {
        $tableheader .= '<td>'.mysql_field_name($query,$x).'</td>';
        if($x==10)
            break;
    }
    $tableheader .= "</tr>";
}

if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    $row = 1;
    while($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        if($row == 1) {
            echo $tableheader;
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row}</td>";
        foreach($field as $val) {
            echo "<td>{$val}</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        if($row==85) {
            break;
        }
        $row++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output("memberdata.pdf", 'I');
```

Comment: as far as i guess, its memory issue. Try to fix your code to use as little memory as it can and allocate little more memory and it will work.

Comment: Try to on display errors. Seems that its getting `timeout`.

Comment: That's what i thought so too, do you have a cleaner way to create the PDF without using the Writehtml function? i think it that the one that uses large memory because it converts the table tags to PDF formats..

Comment: Rikesh.. no it doesnt timeout.. i've set the timeout to 0 and confirmed it in phpinfo.. i've also set the momory to 800M cause that's the only allowable maximum memory usage in our server.

Comment: If you have limited memory on server then, is it allowed to generate more than one file instead of all records in one file?

Comment: it should just be in one file.. that's why i asked this question because i have limited time to make this functionality..

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for people who get here by googling, add this at the beginning of your code:

```
// Increase max_execution_time. If a large pdf fails, increase it even more.
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180);
// Increase this for old PHP versions (like 5.3.3). If a large pdf fails, increase it even more.
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 1000000);
```

The report generation dies because of a preg_replace() used by TCPDF. It was a PHP bug for older versions (mine is 5.3.3), preg_replace() returns null silently when the string is too long. See this:
http://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/discussion/435311/thread/f7f96b04